# SVN Checkout: Ignore file extensions

Tags: svn, cygwin

How has this not been explicitly asked?

I have a repo with a bunch of bulk in it (.mp3, .mp4, .wav). Don't ask, it just has this and there's nothing I can do about that.

What I'm looking *to* do is ignore those file extensions when I checkout the branch.

I've tried setting **global-ignores** in .subversion/config but this isn't working and I haven't quite figured out if this applies to checkouts.

Also, I'm running cygwin so I'm assuming I'm editing the subversion config installed in cygwin.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *ignore* is to prevent files from being accidentally added into the repository.

Let's say your a C shop. In C, your source code is `.cpp` or `.c` files. When you build, you get a bunch of `.o` object files - one for each source file. You don't want to add these files because they'll change with each build.

Subversion, like most version control systems allow you to *ignore* these files -- as long as they are not currently checked into the repository. When you set the *ignore* option (there are several ways to do this). These files won't show up as unknown files when you do a `svn status`. They won't be added if you do a `svn add $dir`.

However, if files are already in the repository, those files can't be ignored. Ignoring is only for files that haven't been added.

What you can do is use *sparse checkouts*. The `svn co` command uses the `--depth` parameter and the `svn up` uses `--set-depth`. You can do `svn up --set-depth=ignore *.mp3` to get rid of the MP3 files from your working directory. Doing an initial checkout to ignore certain files and not others is trickier.

Comment: Are you suggesting I checkout the bulky branch, and immediately do an svn up --set-depth=ignore *.mp3 *.mp4 etc, delete the working copy, and re-checkout, and then the files will be ignored?

Comment: No, the files will only be _ignored_ in that working copy. You delete it, and you have to do it all over again. If the MP3 and MP4 files were in separate directories, you could use `svn co --set-depth=none` to get an empty checkout, then use `svn up --set-depth=infinity $dir` to only have the files in `$dir` in your working copy. You cannot _ignore_ files that are already in Subversion. You can remove them, or not use them in your working directory by using _sparse_ checkouts and updates.